# Getting Error while installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

The following are the errors

```
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-cov>=2.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-filter-subpackage>=0.1, which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 has requirement wrapt==1.11.*, but you'll have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
```

Here are the command i ran

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\pbdgr> pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (459.2 MB)
Collecting gast==0.3.3
  Using cached gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Processing c:\users\pbdgr\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\3f\e3\ec\8a8336ff196023622fbcb36de0c5a5c218cbb24111d1d4c7f2\termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.12.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3"
  Downloading scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (30.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 30.9 MB 4.9 kB/s
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1
  Using cached wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
Processing c:\users\pbdgr\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\cc\af\1a\498a24d0730ef484019e007bb9e8cef3ac00311a672c049a3e\absl_py-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0
  Downloading h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.5 MB 68 kB/s
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.8.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.12.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Using cached tensorboard-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 MB)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0
  Using cached numpy-1.18.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.8 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (454 kB)
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Using cached grpcio-1.29.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.3 MB)
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.8
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-47.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 583 kB 6.4 MB/s
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.6.0.post3-py3-none-any.whl (777 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Collecting requests<3,>=2.21.0
  Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"
  Using cached importlib_metadata-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl size=19558 sha256=7a215ea71ba7f73d5bba670cb19aa2ad29800ba87d69836b10307c2d222a5a7f
  Stored in directory: c:\users\pbdgr\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\62\76\4c\aa25851149f3f6d9785f6c869387ad82b3fd37582fa8147ac6
Successfully built wrapt
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-cov>=2.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-filter-subpackage>=0.1, which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 has requirement wrapt==1.11.*, but you'll have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: gast, termcolor, six, numpy, scipy, wrapt, absl-py, opt-einsum, wheel, h5py, keras-preprocessing, setuptools, protobuf, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, google-auth, werkzeug, tensorboard-plugin-wit, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, zipp, importlib-metadata, markdown, grpcio, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, astunparse, google-pasta, tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: gast
    Found existing installation: gast 0.3.3
    Uninstalling gast-0.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled gast-0.3.3
  Attempting uninstall: termcolor
    Found existing installation: termcolor 1.1.0
    Uninstalling termcolor-1.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled termcolor-1.1.0
  Attempting uninstall: six
    Found existing installation: six 1.14.0
    Uninstalling six-1.14.0:
      Successfully uninstalled six-1.14.0
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.18.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.18.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.18.1
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.1
  Attempting uninstall: wrapt
    Found existing installation: wrapt 1.11.2
    Uninstalling wrapt-1.11.2:
      Successfully uninstalled wrapt-1.11.2
  Attempting uninstall: absl-py
    Found existing installation: absl-py 0.9.0
    Uninstalling absl-py-0.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled absl-py-0.9.0
  Attempting uninstall: opt-einsum
    Found existing installation: opt-einsum 3.2.1
    Uninstalling opt-einsum-3.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled opt-einsum-3.2.1
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.34.2
    Uninstalling wheel-0.34.2:
      Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.34.2
  Attempting uninstall: h5py
    Found existing installation: h5py 2.10.0
    Uninstalling h5py-2.10.0:
      Successfully uninstalled h5py-2.10.0
```